# How to convert SVG to WriteableBitmap in UWP C#

Tags: c#, svg, uwp

We can load SVG from 1703 in UWP. 
Can anyone provide a mechanism, 
how to covert SVG to WriteableBitmap in C# UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such api could covert SVG to `WriteableBitmap` image directly, Because when we convert file to `WriteableBitmap` we need use `BitmapDecoder` class like the following, but [`BitmapDecoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder?view=winrt-18362#image-formats) does not support svg type.

```
private static async Task<WriteableBitmap> OpenWriteableBitmapFile(StorageFile file)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        WriteableBitmap image = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
        image.SetSource(stream);

        return image;
    }
}
```

And currently we have a workaround that use `RenderTargetBitmap` to render your image control and convet `RenderTargetBitmap` to `WriteableBitmap` with following.

```
private async void RenderTargetBitmapToWriteableBitmap(UIElement element)
{
    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await bitmap.RenderAsync(element);
    var pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    byte[] pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
    var wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)bitmap.PixelWidth, (int)bitmap.PixelHeight);
    using (Stream stream = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
    }
}
```