# Eraser functionality for an image in UWP(Universal Windows Platform)

Tags: c#, image-processing, uwp

I want to implement a functionality where user can erase an image upon mouse/cursor movement. When user moves the cursor over the image those portions of the image should be erased. Any reference where same functionality is implemented? Sample soln is highly appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to implement a functionality where user can erase an image upon mouse/cursor movement.

This could be easy approach with UWP InkCanvas control, you could place image control under the InkCanvas, and set InkCanvas default DrawingAttributes as white color.

**xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <Image x:Name="ImageRender" Source="Assets/Butterfly.png" />
    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Loaded="inkCanvas_Loaded" />
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes =
        Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse |
        Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen;
    }

    private void inkCanvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InkDrawingAttributes attributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
        attributes.PenTip = PenTipShape.Rectangle;
        attributes.Size = new Size(10, 10);
        attributes.Color = Colors.White;
        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(attributes);         
    }
}
```

And if you want to save the edited image, please call `RenderTargetBitmap` `RenderAsync` method to render current root grid as an image. For more detail please refer to this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61539680/7254781).

Comment: But with this approach. I guess we are drawing on top the image but to be precise we are not modifying individual pixels of the image right.In my case while erasing i need my pixel data to be modified

Comment: Yep,   it's more complex for pixels modifying, you may need to coustom draw method and record the drawed position, and replace the image modified positon with drawed pixel data. But currenly there is no official code sample for this, please feel free post your requirement with windows feedback hub app.